# Swift: Cannot convert from string to int (using slider tag)

Tags: ios, string, swift, int

```
let device = devices[indexPath.row]
let deviceTag = device["deviceID"] as? String
cell.slider.tag = deviceTag
```

I get an error from the above: *Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Int'*

This doesn't work (below):

```
cell.slider.tag = Int(deviceTag)
```

or what "fix-it" provides:

```
cell.slider.tag = Int(deviceTag!)!
```

Comment: try this let deviceTag = device["deviceID"]  cell.slider.tag = Int(deviceTag)!

Comment: What "it doesn work means"? It doesn't compile, it throws a runtime error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set optional while casting from string. Try the below code.

```
let device = devices[indexPath.row]
let deviceTag = device["deviceID"] as! String
cell.slider.tag = Int(deviceTag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're 100% sure the value of the dictionary `device` is an Int you shouldn't implicitly unwrap those optionals.

You can use:

```
if let deviceTag = deviceTag, tag = Int(deviceTag) { cell.slider.tag = tag }
```

or

```
cell.slider.tag = Int(deviceTag) ?? 0
```

But looking at your examples, it seems like `deviceTag` isn't a number at all. Perhaps you should look in your debug area (left panel) to see what the value is or simply `print(deviceTag)` to see what the value is.